# How to check if C++ abstract method is defined at runtime

Tags: c++, methods, runtime, virtual, abstract

How to check if C++ abstract method is defined at runtime

```
class ABase{
public:
 virtual void do1() = 0;
};

class BBase: public ABase{
public:
 virtual void do1(){}
};

class CBase: public ABase{
public:
};

ABase * base = rand() % 2 ? new BBase() : new CBase();
if(&(base->do1) != 0)
  base->do1();
```

This gives error.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: No. And what would be the use?

Comment: There is no virtual method here.  See my answer below.

Comment: Of course this gives errors - __compilation errors__. Or is the missing `virtual` just a typo/pasto, and you're talking or __runtime errors__? Or is it __compilation errors__ in that funny (and wrong) comparison? If so, which ones? It's impossible to say with such a sloppy question. I'm voting to close it, because the way it is it cannot be reasonably answered.

Comment: The whole code is bogus, it statements outside of a function and you can't take the address of a member function like `&base->do1` you can only do `&ABase::do1` but the whole premise for writing code to attempt to do what the question asks is false. I think the question can be "answered" even if the answer has to beg the question.

Comment: Yes. That method is virtual in real life. My mistake when I was typing question.

Comment: I have corrected original question

Comment: @Max: This still doesn't tell the exact error you're seeing and, if it's a compile-time error, which line you get it for. Nevertheless, one can now make reasonable assumptions (compile-time error for bogus-syntax plus misunderstanding a concept), so I have removed my down-vote. (Oh, and you should properly @address people in comment replies, so your replies show up in their Responses tab.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can't instantiate an abstract class, any class you encounter at runtime will not have any pure virtual methods (unless you're in a constructor or destructor at the time), they'll all have been overriden with a non-pure overrider. There is nothing to check.

Answer (score 4):

An abstract method must be implemented in order for the class to be instantiated.  There's no such thing as checking whether a method is implemented, the compiler will do this for you.  In this case, you can't have a CBase object because it has abstract methods.

Answer (score 3):

CBase is abstract because it does not override ABase::do1(). Therefore, you cannot instantiate it. Or rather, that's what would happen if you had declared do1() as virtual. But for now, it just won't compile.

Would be nice to know why you want to do this, though.

Comment: My mistake it is virtual. MS VC++ compiles classes with unimplmented abstract methods and I get eception at run time only when abstract method is called. I guess 0 is placed VTABLE for such methods.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler won't let you create an instance of a type that doesn't define all abstract methods. In your example above the call to **new CBase()** will generate a compile time error along the lines of "cannot instantiate abstract type".

Comment: MS VC++ compiles it. and I get exception at runtime when I call such method. (I made mistake in first post. Method is virtual)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check if the method is implemented at runtime (you can't in this case anyway) because CBase *must* implement do1() to satisfy inheriting from ABase.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate the `CBase` since it's ... abstract, i.e. does not implement all pure virtual functions of its parents.

The easiest would probably be to define a stub implementation in the `ABase`:

```
class ABase {
public:
 void do1() { /* do nothing */ }
};

class BBase: public ABase {
public:
 void do1() { /* do something */ }
};

class CBase: public ABase {};

ABase * base = rand() % 2 ? new BBase() : new CBase();
base->do1();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you remember to make do1() virtual you could check &ABase::do1, &BBase::do1 and &CBase::do1 at runtime. I am not convinced that comparing &ABase::do1 and &CBase::do1 will return the same value just because CBase has not overridden the function, and whether just because it does on one system means it always will.

Whilst you may be able to test these at runtime you would not be able to use the information to create an object of the class CBase if it is not abstract as it will fail to compile when it is.

You could instead do it the "C" way though: have a table of function pointers that can be NULL, check if one of them is NULL, and create a struct of such an instance or invoke it if it isn't.